# xterm: Disable Left Alt from producing ø

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xterm

I'm on latest debian testing with i3wm on two different laptops.

```
Linux mango 4.19.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.16-1
```

When I press LeftAlt + x I get "ø". And other special chars with other keys.

I want to disable it, as I assume it is what is stopping me from using Alt-x in emacs, which should be bound to "execute-extended-command" by default. But it only says "ø is undefined".

It does not seem to be the compose key though, as running:

setxkbmap -model pc105 -option compose:caps

Does not affect Alt-x's behavior. Where is this configured?

---

Update to clarify:
I'm using uxterm and terminal emacs "-nw". I added `XTerm.vt100.metaSendsEscape: true` to .Xdefaults and .Xresources but it had no effect.

Here is the output of `xkbcomp $DISPLAY -`
https://pastebin.com/BFnV4Zdz

Comment: No it is not the compose key: This key works very differently e.g. `«compose»` followed by `o` followed by `/`, to get `ø`.

Comment: Have you tried `«super key»` +`x`? `«super key»` is the one with a logo on it.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I use the windows key as modifier for i3wm. Super+x locks my screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's curious; it's the **Right** Alt which is AltGr and should generate such characters, but no file under `/usr/share/X11/xkb` seems to map AltGr+x to ø.

I suspect that you're running emacs in a terminal emulator -- in which case you should let the terminal emulator map Alt to Esc instead; in `xterm`, you can do that with

```
*.vt100.metaSendsEscape: true
```

If you're not running emacs in a term emulator, then please post the whole output of `xkbcomp $DISPLAY -` somewhere and link it from your question.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that myself. Yes, I run uxterm and emacs -nw but I get the ø also outside of emacs. I added the output to my question. Thank you :)

Comment: if it's uxterm, you should probably use `UXTerm.vt100...`. Try with `uxterm -xrm '*.vt100.metaSendsEscape: true'`, and if it works, add that to `~/.Xresources`.

Answer (score 1):

It might be built into the application (emacs itself, or a terminal if you're using "emacs -nw").  xterm does this, for instance (as documented originally in the [**`eightBitInput`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:eightBitInput) resource, or later, in [**`metaSendsEscape`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:metaSendsEscape)), and some other programs (such as st) copy it.

The feature was implemented in xterm in [2003](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_183):

> modify handling of **`eightBitInput`** resource in UTF-8 mode to translate the value into UTF-8. Otherwise an illegal UTF-8 code is sent to the application (report by Bram Moolenaar).

Comment: When I run xterm instead of uxterm, alt+x indeed behaves differently. Like backspace